# Your Phone app doesn't work anymore, it doesn't even link to the phone

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-edge, your-phone

I'm on Windows 11 and recently I completely uninstalled MS Edge (MS Edge & MS Edge Update, not the MS WebView2) using *Uninstall Tool* by *CrystalIDEA* (you can't uninstall it through normal operations or via cmd/PowerShell) now the Your Phone app doesn't work anymore:
when you try to link your phone and your computer by generating the QR code, it says that an error occurred and that it depends from them (but it's probably due to the uninstallation of MS Edge, in fact I remember of seeing an exe file in the task list that was related to the Your Phone app and had **-edge** in the name).

Can someone explain me if this issue is related to the uninstallation of MS Edge or not and, if related, how to solve it without reinstalling MS Edge? (if possible ofc)

Comment: Try reinstalling Your Phone   .....   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-cant-reinstall-the-your-phone-application/fc6d8e65-b2da-4687-9f65-4390eff9f8dd    ... You can also Repair Edge (System, Apps)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this is indeed a case where MS Edge is required. I would install MS Edge again to test if that fixes the issue, and decide from there if you want the YourPhone app and MS edge or neither.

Comment: Your issue absolutely is linked to uninstalling Microsoft Edge. I see no way to bypass the requirement of Microsoft Edge with an application that requires it.

Comment: Some products, such as earlier versions of Zoom, rely on MSEDGEWEBVIEW2.EXE, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/end-user-faq. Rather than *remove* Edge from Windows, it makes more sense to *disable* it using tools such as *EdgeBlock* from https://www.sordum.org/ .